# How to end process while quiting, Firefox

Tags: firefox-for-android, cache, processes

Firefox has a quit button in it's menu. My settings are check marked to clear all data upon closing. However, quitting Firefox is still leaving the process running and the cache non-empty. So to really quit, I have to: Settings | Apps | Firefox, then tap 'Force stop' and 'Clear cache'.  I end up doing this a couple times a day.  A couple times a year I mistakenly tap 'Clear data', which is disastrous because settings and add-ons are lost.

The mozilla website maintains that stopping and clearing are OS tasks.  So here I am.

How can I, an end user, stream line this? perhaps configuring the OS to end the process when the firefox quits?

Short of that, is it possible for an end user to add to the homescreen a shortcut to: Settings | Apps | Firefox

Comment: On Android 7+ you can restrict `RUN_IN_BACKGROUND` using `appops`. But forcing an app to be killed when it's not in foreground won't clear its filesystem cache. Android manages apps cache and clears when needed. On Android 8+ there's also filesystem quota allotted to every app. However to clear cache repeatedly you need to use third party task scheduler app.

Comment: The app cache varies depending on what sites were visited, hence this is a privacy issue.  Firefox has detailed settings to "Clear private data on exit". Even with all the boxes ticked, the app cache is still not empty.  There is a disconnect here.

Comment: Added to the Q a question RE shortcuts

Answer (score 1):

The regular Firefox for Android is not a privacy-focused browser, it's a general purpose browser with (IMHO) the best privacy defaults that balances privacy and day-to-day usability, but it's not meant for high privacy.

You should use Firefox Focus instead, which is actually designed to be an incognito browser. Additionally, if you really need the highest level of privacy, you should be using Torbrowser.

Comment: Firefox Focus is only available for Apple devices:  https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/focus#w_install-firefox-focus. Assuming you know otherwise, would Focus still leave residue upon quitting? that is, will the process still be running, carrying a a bulked up cached? I think your answer will be yes, in which case your A doesn't address the Q,

Comment: @Mick Firefox Focus is also on the [Google Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.mozilla.focus) though...

Comment: Thanks. Then I'll look harder on mozilla for their info on Focus for Android, and for an APK on their website. But it still leaves open the question of residue in the OS after quitting.  https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%22fiorefox+focus%22+android&ia=web

Comment: typo in my link above: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%22firefox+focus%22+android+site%3Amozilla.org&ia=web